# Crossfade text on click of element without it jumping down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to allow the user to click elements on my site which load different text into a div at the bottom of the page. When they click an image, the text crossfades correctly with the code I currently have but as both of them are on the page at the same time, one div jumps down a line while the other fades out. Is there a better way to do this so that it doesn't jump around?

You can see my working example in this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ymj/241/

```
$("a[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();  // prevent navigating
  var selector = $(this).data("toggle");  // get corresponding element
  $("div").fadeOut(function(e) {
     $(selector).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div1">
    <img src="http://192.241.203.146/assets/img/author.jpg">
</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="#div2">
    <img src="http://192.241.203.146/assets/img/author.jpg">
</a>

<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
```

Any help appreciated. Still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach you can think of is setting the divs to `absolute` as only 1 div will be visible at any point of time.

```
div {
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/A8Ymj/242/)**

**[Using class](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/A8Ymj/243/)**

Comment: Unfortunately while this solves my issue it breaks something else on the page so I will need to continue looking :(